# Тип переменных в c#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Что в unity c# обозначает `GameObject[,]` ? что значит эта запятая?

Comment: Двумерный массив элементов типа `GameObject`, для понимая `GameObject[,,]` означает трехмерный массив.

Comment: большое спасибо

Comment: Это касается не только юнити, а в целом C#. `byte[,]` - двумерный массив байт. https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/2.4.php

Comment: спасибо, почитаю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GameObject - это тип данных. Но для простоты давайте возьмем тип данных int - число.

int - это одно число. Одно единственное.
int[] - это массив. Несколько чисел: `{4, 8, 2, 34, 27, 123456789}`
int[,] - это двухмерный массив, массив массивов. Например, массив размером 3x4: `int[3, 4]`

```
1  2  3  6
4  21 53 8
24 65 7  2
```

Еще бывают зубчатые массивы int[][]. В таком случае вы можете регулировать размер каждого внутреннего массива.

На мой взгляд в [документации](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/2.4.php) прекрасно описана функциональность, примеры, определения и так далее всех массивов: одномерных, многомерных, зубчатых.